# Expressjs multiple optional parameters trigger request handler twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I need a second pair of eyes because I'm not sure why this is happening...
I want to create 1 request handler which might accept 0 or 1 or 2 parameters eg: `http://hocalhost:3000/{seed}/{size}`, `seed` and `size` parameters must be optional.

However the below example doesn't work and the `console.log` is being printed twice. This doesn't happen if I change the handlers route to `/api/:seed?/:size?`. Why is this happening & what am I doing wrong?

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const express = require('express');
const settings = require('./settings');

const app = express();

const calculateDensity = (s) => {

    return (72 * s) / 180;

}

app.get('/:seed?/:size?', (req, res) => {
        
    console.log('Why am I seeing this log?');

    res.end();

})

app.listen(settings.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${settings.PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: As it is optional parameters you should use a request query parameters? Do you accept an answer with query parameters?

Comment: Nope I'm aware of query params. The thing is that I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: In this case I would recommend using 3 distinct handlers. One for route `/`, `/:seed` another for `/:seed/:size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser automatically called `favicon.ico` after load.
it load twice
for `favicon.ico` and the route we define.

We can resolve it like below code

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
    res.end()
})

app.get('/:seed?/:size', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url)
    if (req.url !== "/favicon.ico") {
        console.log('Why am I seeing this log?');
    }
    res.end();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is your default route

```
app.get('/:seed?/:size?', (req, res) => {
        
    console.log('Why am I seeing this log?');

    res.end();

})
```

Lets have another route

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        
    console.log('Test called');

    res.end();

})
```

Now on browser `localhost:port/test`
Now which route will call.
As per your code it will consider that you are calling default route, where your first two argument is optioal.

So always default route will called. and test route skipped. Because `test` is now parameter of `default` route. Not another route

> Think deeply Either test route work or default route

Comment: There is only 1 handler, also the handler is being triggered twice (question updated)